# WCF enabled Ajax- how can increase size of Data Length for one [OperationContract]

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

i want to insert the Content of a html editor to DataBase via wcf but when text size is more than 40 lines it does not work out.
How can i increase the size of data length for an only operation Contract ?

i want to set the size just for one Operation Contract because of Security Reasons

Answer (score 3):

It is **not** possible at *Operation level* and has to be done at the **service level**.

If you really have concerns, create a Service which has only this operation and create a dedicated binding where you change the various quota threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this when you define the end-point binding on the client side, sample app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestRunner" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="320" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
```